# Probability-generating function

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

I'm trying to solve the following task:

---

Let $X$ be a random variable with values in $\mathbb{N}\cup \{0\}$ and generating function $g_X(s):=\mathbb{E}[s^X]$ for $s\in[0,1]$

Define $$T(s)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty s^n P(X>n)$$

a) Prove that when both sides are well defined
$$(1-s)T(s)=1-g_X(s)$$

b) Show that for $s\in[0,1]$
$$\sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty s^j P(X\leq j)=\frac{g_X(s)}{1-s}$$

---

So what I did so far:

a) $$(1-s)T(s)=1-g_X(s)$$
$$(1-s)\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty s^n P(X>n)=1-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty s^n P(X=n)$$
$$(1-s)\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty s^n (1-P(X<=n))=1-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty s^n P(X=n)$$
$$(1-s)\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty s^n (1-\sum\limits_{l=0}^n P(X=l))=1-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty s^n P(X=n)$$

b)
$$\sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty s^j P(X\leq j)=\frac{g_X(s)}{1-s}$$
$$(1-s)\sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty s^j P(X\leq j)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty s^n P(X=n)$$
$$(1-s)\sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty s^j \sum\limits_{l=0}^{j}P(X=l)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty s^n P(X=n)$$

And here I'm stucked. I don't know what I should do and whether this is the right approach, whether I should use Fubini-Tonelli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint for (a): In the sum
$$
g_X(s):=E(s^X)=\sum_0^\infty s^nP(X=n)$$
write $P(X=n)=P(X>n-1)-P(X>n)$, so that
$$
\sum_0^\infty s^nP(X=n)=\sum_0^\infty s^nP(X>n-1) - \sum_0^\infty s^nP(X>n)
$$
Now manipulate $\sum_0^\infty s^nP(X>n-1)$ to make it look like $T(s)$. Second hint for (a):

> You'll need to split out the $n=0$ term from the rest of the sum.

Hint for (b):
$$
\sum s^jP(X\le j) = \sum s^j(1-P(X>j))=\sum s^j - \sum s^jP(X>j)
$$